# I need to get top 5 record from SQL Server query but count of all record which satisfy the where clause condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, ssms

```
select count(1) 
from chatmessage 
where ChatThreadId in ('A84B95F5-10E7-483C-A4C7-73EF4CBF48EC',
                       '85DAFD40-697C-486C-BB3B-86357CFF6A36',
                       '85DAFD40-697C-486C-BB3B-86357CFF6A36',
                       '7EA0C528-F43C-4DAF-9DFC-068E15177033',
                       'D2B15F10-7F6B-421C-8DA0-F8299BD5FFC5',
                       '85DAFD40-697C-486C-BB3B-86357CFF6A36',
                       '7EA0C528-F43C-4DAF-9DFC-068E15177033',
                       '85DAFD40-697C-486C-BB3B-86357CFF6A36',
                       'A852D60D-480A-45E9-B1AF-D51736BC7CBB',
                       'A84B95F5-10E7-483C-A4C7-73EF4CBF48EC',
                       'A852D60D-480A-45E9-B1AF-D51736BC7CBB',
                       'D2B15F10-7F6B-421C-8DA0-F8299BD5FFC5' )
  and MessageType = 1 
  and TenantId = '1B948F4A-67D7-4A50-A458-0CA16DAB4FAD' 
  and Createddate between '2014-06-24 06:43:40.5374427' and '2016-06-24 06:43:40.5374427' 
  and ModifiedDate between '2014-06-24 13:29:03.6922719' and '2016-06-24 13:29:03.6922719'

select top 5     
    ChatMessageId, ChatThreadId, MessageType, Message,
    TenantId, CreatedBy, Createddate, ModifiedDate 
from 
    chatmessage 
where 
    ChatThreadId in ('A84B95F5-10E7-483C-A4C7-73EF4CBF48EC',
                     '85DAFD40-697C-486C-BB3B-86357CFF6A36',
                     '85DAFD40-697C-486C-BB3B-86357CFF6A36',
                     '7EA0C528-F43C-4DAF-9DFC-068E15177033',
                     'D2B15F10-7F6B-42 1C-8DA0-F8299BD5FFC5',
                     '85DAFD40-697C-486C-BB3B-86357CFF6A36',
                     '7EA0C528-F43C-4DAF-9DFC-068E15177033',
                     '85DAFD40-697C-486C-BB3B-86357CFF6A36',
                     'A852D60D-480A-45E9-B1AF-D51736BC7CBB',
                     'A84B95F5-10E7-483C-A4C7-73EF4CBF48EC',
                     'A852D60D-480A-45E9-B1AF-D51736BC7CBB',
                     'D2B15F10-7F6B-421C-8DA0-F8299BD5FFC5' )
  and MessageType = 1 
  and TenantId = '1B948F4A-67D7-4A50-A458-0CA16DAB4FAD' 
  and Createddate between '2014-06-24 06:43:40.5374427' and '2016-06-24 06:43:40.5374427' 
  and ModifiedDate between '2014-06-24 13:29:03.6922719' and '2016-06-24 13:29:03.6922719'
order by  
    CreatedDate desc
```

Comment: Please edit your question and make use of the `{}` button above the edit box. It operates on highlighted text to format it as code

Comment: (Suraj has formatted your code for you; next time you post code, please format it before posting)

Comment: ok, i will do it for sure

Comment: @here, first part of my sql query basically count all the records in table which satisfy the where clause and in next part i had to get only top 5 records which satisfy the same where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do your counting with a window function then it will work out:

```
SELECT top 5
   ...,
   COUNT(*) OVER() as rowCount
FROM
   ...
WHERE
   ...
ORDER BY
   ...
```

If you don't provide anything in the OVER clause of a window function it refers to the whole dataset

Comment: thnx for ur respone, is there any other solution because i cannot use window function here. looking for any efficient sql query only..

Comment: Window function is the most efficient option. Other than that, make a CTE of your query and do `SELECT ..., (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) as rowcount FROM cte WHERE ...`